# Нужен ключ API Гугл карт. Делаю все по инструкции. Ключ не работает. Нужен биллинг судя по ошибке. Биллинг никак не могу подключить!

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

Нужен ключ API Гугл карт. Делаю все по инструкции https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key.
Ключ не работает.

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Нужен биллинг судя по ошибке. Биллинг никак не могу подключить!
Привязывал разные карты и альфабанк и сбербанк и скан и фото паспорта отправлял.

> Мы рассмотрели сведения, которые Вы предоставили. К сожалению, чтобы
> исключить мошенничество и другие противоправные действия, мы оставили
> в силе блокировку Ваших платежей через Google. Согласно нашим
> правилам, причины такого решения не разглашаются.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то за Вас свою карту зарегистрировал? Помочь тут Вам мы ничем не сможем. Обращайтесь в поддержку и пытайтесь решить вопрос.

Comment: Нет конечно. Возможно есть какие-то рекомендации по правильной публикации информации для биллинга? Банк, типа карты, тип документа для подтвержения?

Comment: Не знаю. Я это делал оооооооочень давно и с тех пор консоль разработчика несколько раз изменилась. У меня проблем не возникало. Читайте подробнее инструкцию и справки по этому вопросу. Плюс если Вы в Крыму живете к примеру, то Вас могут просто по территориальному признаку блочить.